# return type must be 'bool' error

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

I have created application using xamarin android need to display and alert box , and based on the value selected I am doing some calculations. so on menu item click I have added below code.

```
public override async Task<bool> OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    bool bTotalResult = false;
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {


        case Resource.Id.action_next:
            bTotalResult = await ShowPayMentTypeDialog();

            return await Task.Run(() => true).ConfigureAwait(true); ;
        default:
            return await Task.Run(() => base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item)).ConfigureAwait(true);;
    }
    //return await Task.Run(() => false ).ConfigureAwait(true);
}
private async Task<bool> ShowPayMentTypeDialog()
{
    bool bResult = false;
    try
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
        View view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.lyt_cash_credit_popup, null);
        Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertbuilder = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbuilder.SetView(view);
        var userdata = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnrPaymentTerms);
        List<cls_spinner_adapter> resultsWayNo = new List<cls_spinner_adapter> {
        new cls_spinner_adapter {SZ_SPINNER_TEXT ="CASH"},
       new cls_spinner_adapter {SZ_SPINNER_TEXT ="CREDIT" } };
        CommonSpinnerAdapter paymentAdapter = new CommonSpinnerAdapter(this, resultsWayNo);
        userdata.Adapter = paymentAdapter;
        alertbuilder.SetCancelable(false)
        .SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate
        {
            if (resultsWayNo[userdata.SelectedItemPosition].SZ_SPINNER_TEXT == "CASH")
            {
                cls_statics.B_IS_PROMOMAYMANET_CASH = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cls_statics.B_IS_PROMOMAYMANET_CASH = false;
            }
            bResult = true;
        })
        .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate
        {
            cls_statics.B_IS_PROMOMAYMANET_CASH = false;
            bResult = true;
            alertbuilder.Dispose();

        });
        Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog dialog = alertbuilder.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return await Task.Run(() => bResult).ConfigureAwait(true);
}
```

But while compiling I am getting below  error.

> return type must be 'bool' to match overridden member `Activity.OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem)`

Comment: So how can I achieve this I just want to show the dialog result as await task.

Comment: await is only working on async Task<bool>
Below error
'await' operator can only be used within an async method.

Comment: [Match the signature of this method, substituting `virtual` for `override`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnOptionsItemSelected/p/Android.Views.IMenuItem/)

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with the posted code, let's go through them.

1. As the compiler is telling you, you cannot change the signature of a method you are overriding. So, change your method to:

   ```
   override bool OnOptionsItemSelected
   ```
2. `.ConfigureAwait(true);` is the *default* configuration, there is no need for explicitly calling it.
3. The following line needlessly starts a new Thread Pool thread just to return a constant value:

   ```
   return await Task.Run(() => true)
   ```

   That code should only be:

   ```
   return true;
   ```
4. Synchronous code should not be marked as asynchronous to try to make them asynchronous. Instead, the caller must call them in an asynchronous way if that's intended. You should get familiar with this excellent article by Stephen Cleary: [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

So, let's put all of these together:

```
//Point 1
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    bool bTotalResult = false;

    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.action_next:
            bTotalResult = Task.Run(() => ShowPayMentTypeDialog()).Result;

            // point 3
            return true;
        default:
            // point 3
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// point 4
private bool ShowPayMentTypeDialog()
{
    bool bResult = false;
    try
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
        View view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.lyt_cash_credit_popup, null);
        Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertbuilder = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbuilder.SetView(view);
        var userdata = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnrPaymentTerms);
        List<cls_spinner_adapter> resultsWayNo = new List<cls_spinner_adapter> {
        new cls_spinner_adapter {SZ_SPINNER_TEXT ="CASH"},
       new cls_spinner_adapter {SZ_SPINNER_TEXT ="CREDIT" } };
        CommonSpinnerAdapter paymentAdapter = new CommonSpinnerAdapter(this, resultsWayNo);
        userdata.Adapter = paymentAdapter;
        alertbuilder.SetCancelable(false)
        .SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate
        {
            if (resultsWayNo[userdata.SelectedItemPosition].SZ_SPINNER_TEXT == "CASH")
            {
                cls_statics.B_IS_PROMOMAYMANET_CASH = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cls_statics.B_IS_PROMOMAYMANET_CASH = false;
            }
            bResult = true;
        })
        .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate
        {
            cls_statics.B_IS_PROMOMAYMANET_CASH = false;
            bResult = true;
            alertbuilder.Dispose();

        });
        Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog dialog = alertbuilder.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    // point 3
    return bResult;
}
```

Comment: Hi getting error here
Task.Run(() => ShowPayMentTypeDialog()).Wait()
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Comment: @Rakesh My bad, that should have been `.Result`

Comment: `.ConfigureAwait(true);` - I would guess he's using StyleCop/FxCop and it's configured to expect it to be explicit.

Comment: @Neil ReSharper or some other extension maybe. I've been on a project with all StyleCop and FxCop rules on, none of them ask you to do such a useless call

Comment: @Camilo : .Result is giving this error Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Spinner

Comment: @Rakesh  That's probably because you want to create an UI object in a different thread